# Unix Double Test Operator and Relational Operators

Tags: bash, unix, operators, conditional-statements, relational

In bash scripts,

```
if [[ $var1 != $var2 ]]
```

is equivalent to the form

```
[ $var1 -ne $var2 ]
```

Why don't the relational operators (`<=`, `>=`) work inside the double test form?  I tried `[[ $var1 <= $var2 ]]` in one of my scripts and it gives me a syntax error.  Must I use the form `[[ $var1 < $var2 || $var1 = $var2 ]]`?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `(( ))` construct:

```
$ (( 4 <= 5 )) && echo ok
ok
$ (( 4 <= 3 )) && echo ok || echo ko
ko
```

or:

```
var1=4
var2=5
if (( var1 <= var2 )) ; then
   echo ok
fi
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on when it is appropriate to use (( vs [[?

Comment: `((` is for numerical expressions. Like `$(( ))`. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html  `[[` is rather for strings (equality, regex, etc.)

Comment: Ah, I see.  So, generally speaking, (( for numerical expressions, and [[ for strings?  My professor is teaching us the single test [ form plus the operators -o, -a, -gt, -lt, etc.  I like the double forms much more and I'd like to adopt those forms in favor of the [ form.  Is there any reason I shouldn't?

Comment: The single `[` is an old construct but it is POSIX compliant, thus portable (will work in any shell). The double construct offers more possibilities but it is not implemented in all shells. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks!  Also, that looks like a very useful page.  I wish had this rather than the lecture notes for the class.  Thanks for sharing.